# How to ensure consistent display of post_meta on Wordpress attachments using CMB2 and type File_List?

Tags: wordpress, cmb2

Found an edge case I could use some help debugging.

I have some post_meta on my attachments, and in almost every instance of the Media Modal it instantiates and saves fine, however, when opening the Add/Upload Media Window from a CMB2 File_List, and using the Upload Files tab, the custom post_meta doesn’t always show up consistently.

After the image is uploaded I can click another image, and then back to the image I uploaded and then it appears.

It feels like it must be an order of operations issue, but I just can’t track down where this would be occuring.

any help would be super appreciated.

I’ve tried playing with the priority of the ‘attachment_fields_to_edit’ filter to no success.